# LINQ to SQL statement similarity?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, linq-to-sql

I've picked up an interesting behaviour with Linq to SQL from C# in VS2015.

I've got a SQL table that I read and I'm displaying the contents on a win form.  Then I update a row's description by using:

```
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

If I look in SQL Server Management Studio, the value has been updated.

And now, these 2 statements are giving me different results.  Any reason why?

```
var x1 = dc.MyTable.Where(p => p.ID == 2).First().Description;
var x2 = dc.MyTable.Where(p => p.ID == 2).Select(x => x.Description).First();
```

x1 contains the incorrect old value, while x2 contains the correct new value.

If I close my form and re-open it, then both x1 and x2 contains the correct value.  It is as if the values are cached somehow.

Comment: Replace First with FirstOrDefault()

Comment: Tried that as well.  It was orginally First() :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataContext from the LINQ to SQL caches all objects, but only the whole entities. So the first query returns objects from cache but the second query has nothing common with cache because it doesn't query for the whole entity. The second query is invoked against database directly.

You can refresh objects in cache using "Refresh" method on a context or you can just create new context object.

Comment: I ran RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues and that works. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to - but your answer was to quick and there is a timer!

Comment: Thanks. I did know about a timer.